# Rails 4 ActiveRecord .where any element in one array is in another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a list of ids that looks something like this:

```
feed_ids = [1,2,3,4,5] # will be filled with random ids
```

I have a Post model that has an attribute parent_ids that might look something like this:

```
parent_ids = [20,14,1]
```

I want to retrieve all records where an element in parent_ids matches an element in feed_ids

I tried this but it's not working:

```
nodes = Post.where(parent_ids: feed_ids)
```

It's not giving me an error but it's also not returning any records.

Comment: are you sure you have posts in the database? you're syntax is correct, i tried on my app.

Comment: `Post.find(parent_ids & feed_ids)`

Comment: @RichardHamilton's comment should work! May feel a bit hackish, but for your particular use case that is the solution. Not sure why you'd need this though. Putting some context/perspective to a problem may help you get better input/insights to the solution

Comment: Understood. I have undeleted my post. Wasn't sure it worked before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` method can take in an array. You could use array intersection here.

```
Post.find(parent_ids & feed_ids)
```

**Disclaimer**

I do not have Rails installed, so I have to go by my instinct.

Also, this might not be the most efficient solution if you have a large data-set. But with relatively few records, it should be fine.