# Rails Query: Any element in Object's Array matches any element in Matching Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Okay sorry if the question is confusing, so i'll clear it up here. For example you have a `Train` object which has a column `stations`. So this `stations` column holds an array of all the train stations that the train travels to. Now for example we have an array of stations called `north_stations`. How can we find all of the `trains` that travels to any of the `north_stations`?

In regular ruby we can do something like this:

```
array_one = [1,2,3,4]
array_two = [2,3,4,5]
(array_one & array_two).any?
```

This returns true if the 2 arrays has at least 1 common element. So how can i pass a database query that returns all the trains that shares an element between `Train.stations` and `north_stations`?

Btw i did come across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38235463/rails-4-activerecord-where-any-element-in-one-array-is-in-another-array) but it is handling with IDs, i tried meddling around with the method in my rails console but couldn't come up with anything.

UPDATE 1:
Okay so i am using Postgres, and the table column type is `string`. In the model i'm using `serialize` to allow it to hold an array of values. An example of the 2 arrays might be,

```
Train.station = [
  "station 1",
  "station 2",
  "station 3"
]
north_station = [
  "station 2",
  "station 4",
  "station 6"
]
```

So since `Train.station` does go to at least 1 of the north_station, i would like to return this particular `Train` object. So when i do `Train.where(??unknown method??)` it would return all the trains that goes to at least 1 `north_station`.

Comment: Could you post your model and also an example of the two arrays?

Comment: Postgres will let you store arrays.  A better approach would be to create a new field `stations` in your `trains` table and use that instead of the string with serialisation.  Then use the build-in PostgreSQL functions for array searches  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html

Comment: Switch the columns to `text` arrays as @SteveTurczyn said. Then try to forget that `serialize` even exists. `serialize` is a trap, it throws a big pile of YAML into your database and there's no sane way to query that so using `serialize` is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Is the only way to pass the query to use pg functions then? Or am i able to use activerecord methods?